# Do an action with some probability in java

Tags: java, random

In Java, I am trying to do an action with a probability p. p is a float variable in my code. I came up with this way of doing it:

```
if( new Random().nextFloat() < p)
  do action
```

I wanted to confirm if this is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: are you OK with the value changing each time? Using `Random()` seems unreliable when you need to keep track of something.

Comment: a side note: for readability and to be on safe side when adding more code to your condition, always use `{}`. 

`if( new Random().nextFloat() < p) {
  do action
}`

Comment: So if I use if (r.nextFloat() < p) where r= new Random(), would that be correct?

Comment: @s_123 see my answer.

Comment: there is no difference in that from what you now have. You will have essentially just moved the instantiation out of the condition. I meant, if you wanted something predictable, you could use another kind of evaluation other than randomly generated number.

Comment: But I will be testing that condition many times. So lets say if I test it 100 times, I want to do action p*100 times on average. Don't I need the same random generator for all conditions then rather than having a new random generator for each condition?

Comment: You action will then just need to be in a for `loop` in that case.

Comment: Do **not** create a new `Random` object each time, that's not how PRNGs are meant to be used!  A single `Random` object provides a sequence of values with good distributional properties.  Multiple `Random` objects created in rapid succession are 1) computationally expensive, and 2) may have highly correlated initial states, thus producing highly correlated outcomes.  `Random` actually works best when you create a single instance per program and keep drawing from it, unless you really really know what you're doing and have specific reasons for using correlation induction strategies.

Comment: @pjs Thanks! That is what I was exactly making sure!

Comment: According to the javadoc of the `nextFloat()`, it's not that precise dealing with probability by float. `nextFloat()` returns 2^24 possible float values, and  rounding of floating-point numbers may cause error. For example, if you assign `0.1` to `p`, which will be represented as `0x3dcccccd` in hex (and this value is NOT exactly 0.1). And you have **1677722** numbers that will cause `nextFloat() < p` be true, which is the probability of `0.10000002384`, not `0.1`.

Comment: You should accept the answer that is most useful. Your question history shows many questions with no accepted answer, which is no good for the community. You take answers, and you give the answerers what they deserve. Right? ;-)

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ Yes, sorry, my bad. I am new to asking questions at Stack Overflow, and don't quite know the rules :)

Comment: @s_123 not so much a rule, as a way of giving recognition to folks who have taken the time to help you.  Plus you get a boost to your own reputation.

Comment: @s_123 to add to what pjs said, you can always go back to your questions history and [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answers to your previous questions that you found most useful. And don't forget to take a quick [tour], if you haven't already ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*There is a **TL;DR** at the end.*

---

From javadocs for [`nextFloat()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextFloat()) (emphasis by me):

> **`public float nextFloat()`**
>
> Returns the next pseudorandom, **uniformly distributed** float value
>   between 0.0 and 1.0 from this random number generator's sequence.

If you understand what uniform distribution is, knowing this about `nextFloat()` is going to be enough for you. Yet I am going to explain a little about uniform distribution.

In [uniform distribution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UniformDistribution.html), *U(a,b)* each number in the interval [a,b], and also all sub-intervals of the *same length* within [a,b] are equally probable, i.e. they have equal probability.

[image: uniform]

In the figure, on the left is the PDF, and on the right the CDF for uniform distribution.

For uniform distribution, the probability of getting a number less than or equal to n, *P(x <= n)* from the distribution is equal to the number itself (look at the right graph, which is cumulative distribution function for uniform distribution). That is, *P(x <= 0.5) = 0.5*, *P(x <= 0.9) = 0.9*. You can learn more about uniform distribution from any good statistics book, or some googling.

#### Fitting to your situation:

Now, probability of getting a number less than or equal to p generated using `nextFloat()` is equal to p, as `nextFloat()` returns uniformly distributed number. So, to make an action happen with a probability equal to p all you have to do is:

```
if (condition that is true with a probability p) {
    do action
}
```

From what is discussed about `nextFloat()` and uniform distribution, it turns out to be:

```
if(randObj.nextFloat() <= p) {
    do action
}
```

#### Conclusion:

What you did is almost the right way to do what you intended. Just adding the equal sign after `<` is all that's needed, and it doesn't hurt much to leave out the equal sign either!

---

P.S.: You don't need to create a new `Random` object each time in your conditional, you can create one, say `randObj` before your loop, and then invoke its `nextFloat()` method whenever you want to generate a random number, as I have done in my code.

#### Comment by [pjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612890/do-an-action-with-some-probability-in-java#comment60823142_36612890):

Take a look at the comment on the question by [pjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612890/do-an-action-with-some-probability-in-java#comment60823142_36612890), which is very important and well said. I quote:

> Do **not** create a new `Random` object each time, that's not how PRNGs are
>   meant to be used! A single `Random` object provides a sequence of values
>   with good distributional properties. Multiple `Random` objects created
>   in rapid succession are 1) computationally expensive, and 2) may have
>   highly correlated initial states, thus producing highly correlated
>   outcomes. `Random` actually works best when you create a single instance
>   per program and keep drawing from it, unless you really really know
>   what you're doing and have specific reasons for using correlation
>   induction strategies.

---

#### TL;DR

What you did is *almost* the right way to do it. Just adding the equal sign after `<` (to make it `<=`) is all that's needed, and it doesn't hurt much to leave out the equal sign either!

Comment: @pjs No no no, you don't have to delete the comment! People need to see who shared those valuable information in the first place, don't they. ;-)

Comment: @SHadowfax the reason I did not include the equals sign in my condition is that nextFloat generates numbers from 0(inclusive) to 1(exclusive). Now lets say my probability is 0, then the action should never happen, but if included the equals sign it would happen when nextFloat generates 0.

Comment: @s_123 If there is a chance p can be 0, you should use only `<`. In that case, statistically speaking, probability of occurrence of the action will actually be *slightly* less than p, instead of being p. Please note that that *slightly* is very slight indeed, and it won't hurt much, as I said in the answer. Hope you understand what I intend to mean :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  That is correct (from a pure probability perspective).  `Random().nextFloat()` will generate a number between `0.0` and `1.0` exclusive.  So as long as your probability is as a float in the range `0.0` and `1.0`, this **is** the correct way of doing it.

You can read more of the exact `nextFloat()` documentation [**here**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextFloat()).

Comment: Thanks. So I am concerned about whether to make a variable r=new Random() and use that for generating random floats between 0.0 and 1.0 or to use new Random() every time because I will performing {do action} many times and on average, I want to perform it p*100 times for every 100 times I test it.

Comment: That many operations is easy.  You should be fine.  If you want, you can create an instance outside of the loop.  The garbage collector will get all of your old instances already, so it shouldn't really matter.

Comment: Note that `Random().nextFloat()` generates a value between 0.0 and 1.0 but not 1.0 whereas a probability can be 1 (100%). Hope it doesn't hurt your scenario.

Comment: @ViralSheth Thanks for pointing out! It doesn't hurt my scenario because I am checking that Random.nextFloat() < p. So if p is 1, all numbers generated will always be less than 1, and so the action will be done every time.

Comment: @intboolstring I am not that concerned about memory allocation. I am more concerned that the action happens p*100 times for every 100 times I  check the condition. So if I use a new Random generator for every condition, would it evenly generate all the numbers between 0.0 and 0.1 for, say 100 times? In other words, is the randomness preserved among different instances of random generators?

Comment: Yes.  When it says uniformly distributed between 0 and 1, it means *asymptotically*.  As in, if you were to generate 100 billion random numbers using this, then you would get something uniform.  You should be fine.

Comment: @ViralSheth, that doesn't seem right. From the official documentation: `The general contract of *nextFloat* is that one float value, chosen (approximately) uniformly from the range 0.0f (inclusive) to 1.0f (exclusive)`

Comment: @Dadani. Right. So right there the docs say 1.0f is exclusive meaning that it is not included.